# The action of a p:commandButton reload the page just once at the first click (or action) when the navigator is fresh started

Tags: jsf, primefaces, jsf-2.2

I hope you are well.

I have a problem with the login page of a Maven Web Application. When connecting a user, the connection button, at the first click, refreshes the page and does not contact my ManagedBean, at the second click everything works correctly. I had to see similar problems but in my case it happens only when the browser is started for the first time (i.e when I close the browser completely and restart it and try to connect to the application for the first time, the problem arises but when I have already logged in once and the browser remains running, no problem).
I have tried some solutions proposed but they didn't work at all ... I think I have sought but I hope that if this is not the case, someone could point me to a solution and if not, I hope someone could have an idea about this problem.
I am using Java EE 7 with JSF (2.2)/primefaces (6.1) and Maven.

Here is my login form:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
  xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
  xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
  xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">

<h:head>
    <f:facet name="first">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0"/>
        <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes" />
        <link type="image/vnd.microsoft.icon" rel="shortcut icon" href="./resources/serenity-layout/images/favicon.ico"/>
    </f:facet>
    <title>#{appBean.appName} #{appBean.appVersion}</title>
    <h:outputScript name="js/layout.js" library="serenity-layout" />
    <h:outputScript name="js/ripple.js" library="serenity-layout" />
</h:head>

<h:body styleClass="login-body">
    <h:form>
        <p:growl id="growl" showDetail="true" autoUpdate="true" life="10000"/>
        <div class="login-panel ui-fluid">
            <div class="login-panel-header">
                <a href="./"><p:graphicImage name="images/logo-slim.png" library="serenity-layout" /></a>
            </div>
            <div class="login-panel-content">
                <div class="ui-g">
                    <div class="ui-g-12">
                        <h1>Connexion à #{appBean.appName} #{appBean.appVersion}</h1>
                    </div>
                    <div class="ui-g-12">
                        <h:panelGroup styleClass="md-inputfield">
                            <p:inputText autocomplete="off" value="#{loginBean.user.username}" required="true" requiredMessage="Votre nom d'utilisateur est requis"/>
                            <label>Nom d'utilisateur</label>
                        </h:panelGroup>
                    </div>
                    <div class="ui-g-12">
                        <h:panelGroup styleClass="md-inputfield">
                            <p:password autocomplete="off" value="#{loginBean.user.password}" required="true" requiredMessage="Votre mot de passe est requis"/>
                            <label>Mot de passe</label>
                        </h:panelGroup>
                    </div>
                    <div class="ui-g-12">
                        <p:commandButton id="saveBtn" action="#{loginBean.login()}" ajax="false" value="Connexion" icon="ui-icon-person" />
                    </div>

                </div>
            </div>
            <div style="border-top: #E3E3E3 solid 1px;text-align: center;">
                <p>Copyright © 2016 - #{appBean.currentYear} | <a href="http://******" target="_blank">****</a>. Tous droits réservés.
                </p>
            </div>
            <div class="login-panel-header">
                <span style="color: whitesmoke;">Avec l'appui du programme</span> <a href="https://******" target="_blank">
                    <p:graphicImage name="images/****.jpg" library="serenity-layout" />
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </h:form>
    <h:outputStylesheet name="css/layout-#{userPreferences.layout}.css" library="serenity-layout" />
</h:body>

</html>
```

And here is my ManagedBean:

```
@ManagedBean
@SessionScoped
public class LoginBean implements Serializable {

    private User user = new User();

    public String login() {
        try {
            Gson gson = new Gson();
            Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient();

            WebTarget target = client.target(contextPath).path("users").path("login");
        String response = target.request(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                .post(Entity.json(new Login(user.getUsername(), user.getPassword())), String.class);
        user = gson.fromJson(response, User.class);

        HttpSession session = SessionUtils.getSession();
        session.setAttribute("username", user.getUsername());
        session.setAttribute("token", user.getToken());

        return "dashboard?faces-redirect=true";
    } catch (Exception e) {
        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(
                null,
                new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR,
                        "Problème de connexion",
                        "Nom d'utilisateur ou mot de passe incorrect"));
    }
    return null;
}

public String logout() {
    HttpSession session = SessionUtils.getSession();
    try {
        Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient();
        WebTarget target = client.target(contextPath).path("usertasks").path("unclaim").path("all");
        String response = target.request().accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                .header("Authorization", "Bearer " + session.getAttribute("token"))
                .method("put", String.class);
        return "login?faces-redirect=true";
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.err.println(e.getMessage());
    } finally {
        session.invalidate();
    }
    return null;
}

public void keepSessionAlive() {
    FacesContext fc = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
    HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) fc.getExternalContext().getRequest();
    request.getSession();
}

public void onIdle() {
    RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().execute("PF('timeoutDialog').show()");
}

public User getUser() {
    return user;
}

public void setUser(User user) {
    this.user = user;
}
}
```

Comment: Sure you don't have any security filters in place? And next time, please try to create a [mcve] by removing all irrelevant code while still being able to reproduce the problem

Comment: Your title is confusing... it sounds like it just works on the first click but effectively it only works AFTER the first click, right? And please read [ask] and state what you tried/found/... And does it work with a plain jsf `h:commandButton` and inputs?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. You're right, it only works after the first click.

Answer (score 0):

On which server are you running?

I had the very same problem in my web app, also JEE 7 + Primefaces when running on a Tomcat (which I had to use due to given environment on the server).

After switching to a real JEE application server (WildFly), it worked without having to fix somethin in the code. I didn't investigate it further, but maybe it works for you too.

By the way, if you use JEE 7, you should avoid using the old JSF specific beans, injections, scopes and use CDI annotations instead (so instead of @ManagedBean use @Named and the @SesscionScoped from the javax.enterprise.context package).

Comment: and use 'mordern' namespaces for JSF, maybr link to some Stackoverflow related articles for all suggestions. They are there.

Comment: I am using widlfly server